# Python dynamic inheritance in the middle of a long chain of inheritances

Tags: python, oop

I have

```
class GrandParent

class Parent(GrandParent)

class ChildA(Parent)
class ChildB(Parent)
class ChildC(Parent)
.... // Many such child classes.
```

I have created an alternate `class GrandParent`, let's call it `class GrandParentNew`, whose public methods have same signature as `GrandParent` but just different implementations, and I'd like to gradually roll out this change with as transparently as possible.

My plan is:

1. Copy `class Parent(GrandParent)` to be `class ParentNew(GrandParentNew)`
2. Rename `class Parent(GrandParent)` to be `class ParentOld(GrandParent)`
3. Create a new `class Parent` that will return either `ParentOld` or `ParentNew`, depending on a known condition (eg, reading some flag from a db).

This way, some `Child*` will inherit from the new lineage: `ParentNew(GrandParentNew)`, others will remain on the old lineage, without having to make changes to any of the `Child*` class implementations or signatures (as there are hundreds of those).

Is there a better plan? If not, what is the best way to implement step 3?

Comment: Answers to this question will only be marginally useful to you. The actual answer will depend on tons of details that are not in the question. For instance, are there any direct consumers of the `Parent` class? Do `Child` classes actually need the `Parent` interface, instead of inheriting from `GrandParent`? How likely it is for you to have to introduce `GrandParentNewest` in the forseeable future?

Comment: If you want to inspect some code that's extremely aggressive about dynamic MRO assembly (using it for goal-seeking), you may find https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/isg-state-machine-framework interesting. Mind, it's very, very old (written for Python 2, and unmaintained for more than a decade); but I understand the employer it was written for -- who authorized its release -- continued to use it well after my departure.

Comment: you may try with  a class decorator to intercept and customize the classes

Comment: @jfaccioni 1) there no direct consumers of ``Parent``` class. 2) Yes ```Child``` classes need the ```Parent``` interface (which will NOT change in ```ParentNew```). And it's unlikely to introduce GrandParentNewest